# DataTable: dynamic Group By expression by LINQ or LAMBDA

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, datatable, group-by

i've a DataTable in which i want to Group By for an unspecified number of fields. This happens why user can choose fields on which he wants to group.

So, actually, i push the choise in a List. And on this choise i have to group my DataTable.

Imagine this piece of code (VB or C# is the same):

```
public void groupFieldsFN(DataTable dt, List<string> groupFields){

    var grpQuery = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => [***groupFields***]);
}
```

What can i do ? How can i express GroupBy expression in this context.

Clearly, LINQ or LAMBDA solution is the same.

Thanks in advance for the help.

_

**SOLUTION**

Aleks Andreev's response works! Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom equality comparer in `GroupBy` call. Define your comparer:

```
public class CustomEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    private readonly List<string> groupFields;

    public CustomEqualityComparer(List<string> groupFields)
    {
        this.groupFields = groupFields;
    }

    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        var xCols = groupFields.Select(f => x[f]);
        var yCols = groupFields.Select(f => y[f]);
        var pairs = xCols.Zip(yCols, (v1, v2) => (v1, v2));
        return pairs.All(p => p.Item1.Equals(p.Item2));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        return 42; // force Equals call
    }
}
```

And use it

```
var grpQuery = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r, new CustomEqualityComparer(groupFields));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Andreev. Just a question. I red about GetHashCode forced on a specific value is not the best for performance. What's the right way for using it. How has to be used.

Comment: @kinghomer I've used this to simplify example. If you want to implement `GetHashCode` you can use something like `return obj == null ? 0 : groupFields.Select(f => obj[f].GetHashCode()).Aggregate(397, (c, n) => c ^ n);` where 397 is a prime number to reduce hash collisions